# Android add image on top of another imageView as image below in Layout XML

Tags: java, android, user-interface, layout, imageview

How to create a android Layout where you add a smaller imageView on Top of another Image View. but only half way as the image below. 
Thank.

[image]

this is the sample I try but it does not work:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageCover"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/big_cover_img" />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageProfile"
          android:layout_width="100dp"
          android:layout_height="100dp"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageCover"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:src="@drawable/profile_pic" />

      <!-- android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageCover" -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: adjust your marginTop for imageProfile accordingly and you shuld get it

Answer (score 3):

Use FrameLayout as parent and LinearLayout as child with weight property :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageCover"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/big_cover_img" />
            </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageProfile"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Haresh, thanks for your anwser. But i need to cover image to be less than half of the Layout. If I make the cover image height smaller or make the layout_weight of the bottom LinearLayout. how can I push the Profile image to the top making the same affect ?

Answer (score 2):

Set the second view to be below the first then set top margin of the bottom view to -50 dp or whatever value you want it to overlap